# What is inside of "The Highway"? Why did astronauts end up insane or commit suicide?

Tags: burning-chrome

Did *Hinterlands* by William Gibson mention the source that is behind the death of astronauts? Is it *infohazard*, learning something that can "break" one's mind? Or did the astronauts encounter something malevolent that caused their insanity?

The writing is pretty dense; what idea is the author trying to convey through the story?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jaunt - Similar themes

Comment: We will never know! It's the Fear ... of the Fly ... trapped in an Airport (and the Fear actually materializes at the end)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer fear of ?

Comment: Some kind of mind-shattering Lovecraftian weirdness on the other side

Comment: @Quartz2 _We're like intelligent houseflies wandering through an international airport; some of us actually manage to blunder onto flights to London or Rio, maybe even survive the trip and make it back. “Hey,” say the other flies, “what's happening on the other side of that door? What do they know that we don't?” At the edge of the Highway every human lnguage unravels in your hands except, perhaps, the language of the shaman, of the cabalist, the language of the mystic intent on mapping hierarchies of demons, angels, saints. But the Highway is govned by rules, and we've learned a few of them._

Comment: @DavidTonhofer I wished that the  author would elaborate more on the highway, after reading it felt a bit unsatisfying

Comment: @Quartz2 Well, it's just a literary device. Like the "House of Silence" of the Night Land, or the "Zone" of "Roadside Picnic" or the "Tower" of "Annihilation" etc. It stands in for something _per se_ unknowable.

Comment: I think being unsatisfied is part of the point of the story. We are left without any more understanding than the characters themselves have. There is no omniscient narrator. There are many stories like this, with “The Lady Or The Tiger” being a notable example. We never learn the truth.

Answer (score 3):

My read is that *Hinterlands* is a *2001* gloss over Lovecraftian Cosmic Horror. Perhaps not *literally* the Old Ones, but beyond the vast emptiness of space, there are beings so far beyond us that we're stuck being the cargo cult society tracking for their scraps. There is no Big Black Obelisk to guide us into the next step of evolution. Instead, the refuse cast off and forgotten by *whatever is out there* is enough to advance human science by leaps and bounds.

I mean, Olga Tovyevsky isn't Charles Dexter Ward and we never *see* *them*, described with a list of long adjectives, but what the hitchhikers experience and learn is more than they can handle, so in a Lovecraftian turn, they go mad and kill themselves.